# Laravel: Validation Rule Ignore submitted ID in FormRequest class

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I would like to ignore one of the inputs inside a FormRequest class. Previously, I've already done it on my previous Laravel project using the exact same code (The previous Laravel project was Laravel Version 7). Here is the code of my ignore validation:

```
class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->user = $request->route()->client;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => ['nullable', 'string', 'email', 'max:100', 'unique:users,email,'.$this->user.',user_id'],
        ];
    }
```

The line code "$request->route()->client" is to get the submitted form request data (client is one of the route inside the web.php file).
But when I try this code inside the current project (Current project is Laravel 8). The results was the email was not ignored.

I guess there are something new in Laravel 8 about FormRequest? How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

Here is my route (web.php) code:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

And here is my users table structure:

[image]

I used the resource Controller so the route is simple.

Comment: With regards [to this note in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields), could you confirm if `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middlewares are listed in your global middleware stack since performing the upgrade?

Comment: Yes I have checked both of the middlewares are listed. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following way

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'email' => [
                'nullable', 'string', 'email', 'max:100',
                Rule::unique('users','email')->ignore($this->route()->client,'user_id'),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

and ignore method accept two params

```
ignore($id, $idColumn = null)
```

for the second column default, it treats as the `id` column as the primary key.if not then we should specify the column name.

so there is no need to use a constructor and all

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your suggestion, but the validation still said the email has already taken, which is the ignore is kind of not working? Because there is no error, just the validation is keeps not ignoring the current submitted user_id. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DenjanD .better if you add route and user table structure so I can see where it goes wrong

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @DenjanD is it post reuqest ?

Comment: No, it is a put request

Comment: then your route will be PUT|PATCH       users/{user} so it should be this->route()->user

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Finally my problem has been solved. Btw, how can I change the users/{user} to users/{somethingelse} so that the this->route()->somethingelse ?

Comment: Route::resource('users', UserController::class, ['parameters' => [
    'users' => 'somethink'
]]);  so it will be  PUT|PATCH       users/{somethink}